# Run Gulp script with forever?

Tags: node.js, gulp, forever

Is it possible to run Gulp script with [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever)?

I have Gulp script that would like to run as a daemon, so I could start / stop / list it.

Answer (score 22):

Okay, so I solved it by linking the gulp binary from /usr/bin to my local folder and then simply running the command locally. Like so:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/gulp ./gulp
forever start gulp serve
```

The commands may vary for you but I hope you get the gist of it.

Comment: For me, gulp was at `/usr/local/bin/gulp` so the command was `ln -s /usr/local/bin/gulp ./gulp`. Find out where gulp is by running `whereis gulp`

Comment: same here @apple16, but I could only check my gulp path with `which gulp` - on OSX

Answer (score 9):

if you install `gulp` in your node project, you can do like this:

`forever start node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js [YOUR GULP TASK]`

Answer (score 4):

To give you a programatic answer:

You use the underlying [forever-monitor](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever-monitor) which contains the core functionality which the `forever` CLI package uses.

```
var forever = require('forever-monitor');

gulp.task('server', function () {
    new forever.Monitor('path/to/server-script.js').start();
});
```

You can run multiples of such tasks, you don't need to use special daemon options since gulp tasks use orchestrator under the hood which runs tasks concurrently.

If using CMD+C in the console is not suitable to stop your tasks then you can put it into a variable:

```
var child = new forever.Monitor('path/to/server-script.js');
child.on('event', cb) / child.start() / child.stop()
```

Comment: what's the `server-script.js` content? is it node http server (`http.createServer(function (request, response) {});`) or gulp server(`connect.server({})`)

Comment: @Venugopal it's a normal node server

Answer (score 1):

Install `pm2`

```
$ npm install pm2 -g
```

Now start `gulp`

```
pm2 start gulp serve
```

You can view running services using `pm2 l` and 
Note: sometimes you can see your services running on next to port you specified example: http://localhost:3001 instead of http://localhost:3000

Comment: "pm2 start gulp serve" is not working for me...    Error: Cannot find module '/home/ravisankar/workspace/Javascript/appolo/gulp'    Even i have the module gulp installed

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`forever start -c "gulp" serve`

The `-c` option allows you to use any command.