# Running Gulp in background always

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gulp, rhel

I have to maintain a AngularJS/Node.js application which uses Gulp with browserify. I cannot install npm on server so I unzipped node x64 and added it to the path. The code is compiled locally with node_modules in the code folder. We are unzipping it into a folder in server and executing the `gulp serve &`. The process starts fine, however exits as soon as the user is logged out. Kindly suggest the best way to resolve this issue.

Comment: `gulp serve` is not build in gulp command, it is defined in `gulpfile.js`. So, functionality is depends on what script is in your `gulpfile.js`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use nohup, like

```
nohup gulp serve &
```

Comment: I did try that, the process exits out as soon as i end my ssh terminal session.

Comment: This worked for me... `nohup node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js > /dev/null 2>&1&`

Comment: Not working for me. Anyone want to share some insights?

Comment: @RLaaa Did you find any answer ? Im facing same problem.

Comment: Perhaps this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28543171/run-gulp-script-with-forever

Comment: In Linux/Unix you can run this inside a "screen" session to ensure that the process is not killed even if you terminate the shell window. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HomIzLB-HBc

Answer (score 2):

Following command helped me to fix the issue:

```
forever start node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js
```